# How do you automatically increment cell references when the cells are not next to one another?

Tags: google-sheets, copy, increment, paste

This is what I am trying to do.

This I can do easy (copy/paste, drag, etc.):

| Data |
| --- |
| `=Sheet1!A1` |
| `=Sheet1!A2` |

Yet, I want to be able to do this:

| Data |
| --- |
| `=Sheet1!A1` |
|  |
|  |
| `=Sheet1!A2` |

Instead of this when I copy and paste:

| Data |
| --- |
| `=Sheet1!A1` |
|  |
|  |
| `=Sheet1!A4` |

Answer (score 2):

try instead:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN({Sheet1!A1:A3, IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(Sheet1!A1:A3), 2)/0)}))
```

[image]

Comment: @player1 I am now assume that the cells have to be equal distant from each other. Hence the 2?

Comment: @JosephLouthan yes, 2 stands for "2 empty cells between"